# проброс на 2 хоста 80 порта через mikrotik

Tags: mikrotik, portforwarding

Подскажите, есть вариант пробросить на микротике 2 раза 80 порт на разные хосты? К примеру host1.ru и host2.ru? Или всё же придется покупать отдельно еще один IP? Вешать на одном сервере оба хоста не могу.

Comment: Если речь идет о веб-серверах, то можно использовать микротиковский  веб-прокси [Multiple Web Servers](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Multiple_Web_Servers)

Comment: Я боюсь, пробрасывать придется в итоге не только 80 порт...

Comment: ваш случай ? http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Hairpin_NAT

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать это какими то правилами, включая L7.

Например, если точно не планируете использовать https, то можно матчить http-заголовок, искать в нем хост и перенаправлять в зависимости от этого. (подробнее здесь: http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/Firewall/L7)

Из минусов - это будет очень ресурсоемко, и если микротик будет из класса SOHO, например, 951-й то он может вполне не справиться, когда на сайты станут популярными.

Comment: А вообще я бы в такой ситуации использовал nginx(например) в качестве прокси на одном из хостов, тогда и с https проблем не возникнет.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант сделать так:

`host1.ru` делаем проброс 80 на локальный адрес.

`host2.ru:8080` делаем проброс 80 на другой локальный адрес.

Answer (score -1):

А каким образом вы себе это представляете? Утром порт 80 будет пробрасываться на host1.ru, а вечером host2.ru? 
Это же TCP, он ничего о вышележащем протоколе HTTP не знает. Единственный вариант это поставить какой-нибудь ngingx или transparent proxy, который будет доставать вам контент с разных хостов в зависимости от HTTP-host в запросе.

Comment: Могу предположить, что наверное с nginx самый лучший вариант...